# Decimalize a Fraction

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

### Preamble

A common pain-point when working with [rational numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) and decimals is how infrequently one can represent their rational number as a clean, non-repeating decimal. Let's solve this by writing a program to decimalize (not to be confused with [decimate](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/decimate)) them for us!

### The Challenge

Given a [fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction), check if it can be represented perfectly by a finite decimal number. If it can, output the decimal representation of this fraction. Otherwise, output the input fraction.

### Specifics

Input will be provided as two integers within the range of `[1, 32767]` *(Positive Signed Shorts)*, representing both the Numerator and Denominator. Numbers may be taken in any convenient format or order, including built-in Fraction formats, a single pre-divided floating point number *(of a precision that can accurately represent all possible fractions)*, a deliminated string, an imagine number, [etc](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). The Input is **not** guaranteed to be in simplified form.

A given Input is "Decimalizable" if the Denominator of the Simplified Fraction contains no prime factors other than `2` or `5`.

The Output, given a Decimalizable Input, must be a decimal number. This may be as any convenient format, including a string, char array, or float. It may **not** be a Fraction type. *(Floats are allowed as it is generally trivial to stringify.)* Trailing Zeroes are **not** allowed, though leading zeroes are.

Otherwise, The Output must be Two Numbers signifying the Numerator and Denominator, in any convenient format. The output may **not** be a decimal number, nor a floating point number. Output may optionally be Simplified.

### Test Cases

```
16327 /     4 = 4081.75
  186 /   400 = 0.465
23164 /   100 = 231.64
32604 / 20000 = 1.6302
22764 / 16384 = 1.389404296875
    3 /     6 = 0.5
    1 /     3 = 1/3
 3598 /  2261 = 514/323
 7725 / 18529 = 7725/18529
21329 /  3774 = 21329/3774
12213 /  2113 = 12213/2113
```

### Rules

- [Standard IO Applies](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- [Standard Loopholes Apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so fewest bytes wins!
- Have Fun!

Comment: Is it OK if the float is sometimes given in scientific notation? For example, Python shows `1/16384` as `6.103515625e-05`.

Comment: @xnor So long as it’s accurate like above, sure.

Comment: Why is `7725/18529` not decimalizable?

Comment: @JosWoolley The fraction is not simplifyable, and the denominator `18529`'s prime factors are `7` and `2647`, of which neither are 2 or 5. The true decimal is a number with 882 repeating digits. [Wolfram Alpha for more](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=7725%2F18529)

Comment: Then perhaps you should change "*contains no prime **numbers** other than 2 or 5*" to "***has** no prime **factors** other than 2 or 5*", as I read the former as meaning that none of the digits in the decimal representation were primes other than 2 or 5.

Comment: @JosWoolley Ah, typo on my half. Thanks for catching, I'll correct it.

Comment: So, suggest testcase: `3/6`

Comment: May I output the decimal output as a list of unary numbers as the digits with some constant value to represent a decimal point?

Comment: @noodleman Definitely. Can't imagine why you wouldn't be able to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 86 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 10.75 bytes

```
\/€tǏ25F[|øḋ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwiXFwv4oKsdMePMjVGW3zDuOG4iyIsIiIsIjMvNiJd)

And here I thought I was being clever skipping the challenge text. Takes a fraction as input, which is automatically simplified.

### Explained

```
\/€tǏ25F[|øḋ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠⁪⁪‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
\/€           # ‎⁡Push a copy of the input splitted on "/"
   tǏ25F      # ‎⁢Push the prime factorisation of the denominator with 2s and 5s removed.
        [|øḋ  # ‎⁣If that is empty, convert to decimal.
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: +1 "For once I did some googling" ... and so saved the need to read as far as the 4th paragraph of the challenge... <tongue-in-cheek>

Comment: @DominicvanEssen you telling me people actually read challenge texts and don't just jump to the test cases? :p

Comment: Vyxal Q - why does ```25F``` remove the numbers 2 and 5, instead of removing 25?

Comment: @DominicvanEssen because the `25` is converted to a list of digits. If you wanted to remove 25, you would use `25o`

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 34 bytes

```python
lambda n,d:[n/d,(n,d)][n*1e16%d>0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYxBCsIwEEX3OcVsxESKzcy0SVrRi6iLShULNYZaEU9fk@Cs5vH@/@E735@eXZiW2/60jN3j0nfgi749@rIvZPzU@eg3eEWz6g/6vHzuw3gFbKPZP7ogBz8Xgw/vWartK4zDLNflWqldmKKRt7ygFjRMFkpIVwkAdCZTpbUgRlNlwkhMRicirZMjm13su9SLmf8KgwCuG5eQyKAAa6lOUVdTIwiZmuTY2kogRc5JRP4B)

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 13 bytes

```
?¤/i/¤-p*10¹³
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/3/7QEv1M/UNLdAu0DA0O7Ty0@f///@Z6Bv@NjPQMAA)

Input as two integers (den, num) represented in floating-point format: it's much easier in [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk) to convert a float to an int than the other way around.

```
?¤/i/¤-p*10¹³       # full program
?¤/i/¤-p*10⁰²⁰²     # with arg expansion:
     ¤              # combin: ¤fgxy means f(gx)(gy)
      -             #  f = - = list difference
       p            #  g = p = prime factors
        *10⁰        #  x = 10x arg1
            ²       #  y = arg2
                    # (so this simplifies the fraction,
                    # and returns list of any non-2, non-5 factors
                    # - truthy if there are any, falsy if none)
?                   # fif: ternary if for functions
                    # use the above result to choose from:
 ¤/i             ⁰² #  (if truthy) convert both args to integers & divide
                    #  (Husk outputs real fractions by default)
    /            ⁰² #  (if falsy) just divide
                    #  (keeps input floating-point format)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 246 bytes

```
\d+
$*
^(1+)(\1)*/(\1)*$
1$#2$*1/$#3$*
+`/(1+)\1{9}(0*)$
/$1$+0
+`/(1+)\1{4}(0*)$
$`/$1$+0
+`/(1+)\1(0*)$
$`$`$`$`/$1$+0
+`/(11+)0
/$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1
^(1+)(\1)*/(\1)*$
1$#2$*1/$#3$*
1+
$.&
r`^(?<-1>.)+/1(0)+$
$#1$*00$&
r`((?<-2>.)+)/1(0)+$
.$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hc7JagMxDAbgu15jlOKFjvTLng1KeuxLDGECyaGXHkJuIc8@9WSBkBxigZH9CUmH/fH3bzuv3M80j7tIHGjjEL0b4YNcbiZwZRwgXKXicZKlYsRpODsNnkkYHPUB8g14eqb7/zUetbBeOr3E241Q9q4/6DBt3PfXJ9a1j1Im@VgmVeCgyou6RW1Rf@eaMc/oW8mqZAltFpQsWatZTMshSKLUDL2YtaCus0bQNzaQIdkgqesywcpDDEj/) Link includes faster test cases, as manipulating large numbers in unary is horribly slow. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
^(1+)(\1)*/(\1)*$
1$#2$*1/$#3$*
```

Reduce to lowest terms.

```
+`/(1+)\1{9}(0*)$
/$1$+0
```

Find all factors of `10` in the denominator.

```
+`/(1+)\1{4}(0*)$
$`/$1$+0
+`/(1+)\1(0*)$
$`$`$`$`/$1$+0
```

Find all factors of `5` and `2` in the denominator, and multiply both numerator and denominator by `2` or `5`.

```
+`/(11+)0
/$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1$1
```

If the denominator turned out to have other factors, then convert it back to unary.

```
^(1+)(\1)*/(\1)*$
1$#2$*1/$#3$*
```

Reduce the fraction to lowest terms again, but only if it was converted back to unary.

```
1+
$.&
```

Convert to decimal.

```
r`^(?<-1>.)+/1(0)+$
$#1$*00$&
```

Prepend zeros to the numerator if the denominator is a larger power of `10`.

```
r`((?<-2>.)+)/1(0)+$
.$1
```

Divide the numerator by the denominator if it is a power of `10`.

179 bytes and faster for exact decimals in [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language) 1:

```
+`.+/(.*50*)$
$.(*2*)/$.($1*2*
+`.+/(.*[2468]0*)$
$.(*5*)/$.($1*5*
+`0(/.+)0$
$1
r`^(?<-1>.)+/1(0)+$
0$#1*0$&
r`((?<-2>.)+)/1(0)+$
.$1
/\//&`\d+
*
^(_+)(\1)*/(\1)*$
$.(_$#2*_)/$#3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY1JTsNAEEX3dQ03UQ@ia3IPlhAsOQQmdiRYsGERcX9THSnZ1PRe6V@//35@L3w8@ff9SHtO6HMsFIMDl32UGNC6Y5vgjj9krv3z4ZSHU4ZDHnMKZIzhup/928szv@aQkD2F5IDcxJHcyaAfUAYMd5rtC1fE075@JYhw9lsKfuUQ8VZvkZubJG6WOulxCBbgqtJwBu4VZyIQ5Toj26RSaUYhGldp41q1m4kKWpaOIpWhNSnIvcgCwioLamvmiC0ozPoP) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
+`.+/(.*50*)$
$.(*2*)/$.($1*2*
```

Double the numerator and denominator while the latter ends in `50*`.

```
+`.+/(.*[2468]0*)$
$.(*5*)/$.($1*5*
```

Multiply the numerator and denominator while the latter's last nonzero digit is even.

```
+`0(/.+)0$
$1
```

Cancel out any power of `10` common to both numerator and denominator.

```
r`^(?<-1>.)+/1(0)+$
0$#1*0$&
```

Prepend zeros to the numerator if the denominator is a larger power of `10`.

```
r`((?<-2>.)+)/1(0)+$
.$1
```

Divide the numerator by the denominator if it is a power of `10`.

```
/\//&`\d+
*
^(_+)(\1)*/(\1)*$
$.(_$#2*_)/$#3
```

Otherwise, reduce the fraction to its lowest terms.

Answer (score 4):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 44 bytes

```
[| x y | x 1e16 * y mod 0 > x y / x y /f ? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LZC7TsQwEEV7f8WlpYg941cCYikRDQ2iQhTRkiwr8lISJFbAtwc/4mKkc67la01bH9dx3l6eH58eblAvy3hc0NfrBz6beWg6THOzrpdpPg8rTvP4NZ2HE7rxWHcLboX4EeQ0e6RjcIU7GFVS4a0AqHRJK5UCVRhnBWtyJmradRCFM0KzU8GzUrsPVisWzD7eDzWl2b0uK6MMV65MNSHM/TrnUgtoW5XBMDtK0pKRmkPgPdv4M8tVCiLLhIJJBxme8T43JSEjCuIA8UGivSUKGVH8gfNqttdffOOCOKkhh@sA/fgOhUMKZJ4t7vG2tXndh76eUGz/)

Port of xnor's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264965/97916). The only difference is that it's shorter to return either a ratio or a float instead of bothering with lists.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
`s16°*sÖi`/
```

I/O as a pair \$[nominator,denominator]\$. The output is unsimplified.

Port of [*@xnor*'s Python 3 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264965/52210).

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/odjQ7NAGreLD0zIT9P//jzY0MzYy1zGJBQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##JY0xCsJAEEWvEqYRJDA7M7szu1UabyFCFCxSWQSEFLYewMLeE@gZkpt4kXU3du/zePzLeDwN53ydOmi@90cD3bTB@bW8d7kfSefPdlyeQ4/51uY9kAobemiBoqJ3rhALqUdaWVidR3bub9iqUYm1ENTaoVQOKSKzUmEzDkgxcKoJCScUs/WDy0QmEjj8AA).

**Explanation:**

```python
`           # Pop the (implicit) input-pair, and push both items separately to the stack
 s          # Swap so the nominator is at the top
  16°       # Push 10000000000000000 (10**16)
     *      # Multiply it to the nominator
      s     # Swap so the denominator is at the top again
       Ö    # Check if the nominator with 16 trailing 0s is divisible by the denominator
        i   # Pop, and if this is truthy:
         `  #  Pop and push the input-pair separated to the stack again
          / #  And divide them
            #  (after which this decimal is output implicitly as result)
            # (implicit else)
            #  (output the implicit input-pair instead)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 47 bytes

```
If[Depth[r=RealDigits@#]>3,#,N[#,Tr[1^#&@@r]]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYqxCsIwFEV/pRBwCry899KkHSoZuriIiFuIEKS2BStSs4nfHhu3e885S0zTsMQ032Ieu3y4@354pcmv3XmIj34e5/R2IuxZCnn0Ql5Wj1exc24NIezyaZ2fCdwI7oOGyYKWFTYGtFKyIkajActkMkoDKfXnZAs33JQaeNN12wCRQVlZSzVgU1O7hcjUAltbOtoeECJ/c/4B)

-8 bytes thanx to @att

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the precision of `N`

Comment: Invert the condition `ListQ@Last@#`->`VectorQ@#`

Comment: Or better, check if `Depth[r]` is 3 or 4

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 24 bytes

Unsurprisingly, a port of [xnor's method](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264965/58563) probably leads to the shortest code.

```javascript
p=>q=>p*1e16%q?[p,q]:p/q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc/LbsIwEAXQfb/Cm0pJ1cbz8iNIoR9SsUA0VK0QcQDx@@mYkEVNs5ubo5nrn@11e96dvtPl7Th89tO@m1K3Hrt1esEe/fP4/pFex80q2XHaDcfzcOibw/BV7Sv0TKGujH5S18ZaIxCxCe7przMGo89OAGYHjfhSEaOXrHBRmjReCsbkQRkBLEwRA5XbKORtWjHKwji2AkKtj/9U1LvzU/jOLZeGXRvVEHmcjUOxTA8uBHJ6OjpqZ5cDe5vLlshqdHMI95a3xOa5oEj6K19HXBrmxOZ5@gU)

---

#### Other approach (43 bytes, invalid)

Expects `(p)(q)`. Returns either `[p,q]` or `p/q`.

We multiply by \$5\$ the greatest power of \$2\$ that divides \$q\$ until it's greater than or equal to \$q\$.

This works for all test cases ([at the time of posting](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/264962/3)) but would fail on some others because *the input is not guaranteed to be in simplified form*.

```javascript
p=>q=>(g=n=>n>q?[p,q]:n<q?g(n*5):p/q)(q&-q)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc9NTsMwEAXgPafwCtmIxp7x@CcVSQ@CWFSljYoqJ6aI64dx0ywwZDcvn2aeP/bf@@vh8zx9bdL4fpxP3Tx1fe56OXSp61Ofd6/Tc37bppe8G2R6cmo76axkftxkNR/GdB0vx@YyDvIkwVsMSgr@SCmhtSAToQnu4bcTAqIvjoxZnGnI1woteCoKVsVJ46liFr1hhsasjJE1WG/DULZxxUgrs7ElQ9j6@E9Fvrs8xd65trWxro1sED0sxgFpi39cCOj4dHTYLq4E@jbXLcGy4c0h3FveEl3migLyr3IdYG1YEl3m@Qc)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 125 bytes

```js
f=s=>{[n,m]=s.split('/').map(v=>+v);for(i=n>m?n:m;i>1;i--)if(!(n%i|m%i))[n,m]=[n/i,m/i];return n*1e16%m?`${n}/${m}`:`${n/m}`}

const testCases = [
  { input: '16327/4',     output: '4081.75'        },
  { input: '186/400',     output: '0.465'          },
  { input: '23164/100',   output: '231.64'         },
  { input: '32604/20000', output: '1.6302'         },
  { input: '22764/16384', output: '1.389404296875' },
  { input: '3/6',         output: '0.5'            },
  { input: '1/3',         output: '1/3'            },
  { input: '3598/2261',   output: '514/323'        },
  { input: '7725/18529',  output: '7725/18529'     },
  { input: '21329/3774',  output: '21329/3774'     },
  { input: '12213/2113',  output: '12213/2113'     },
];

for (let { input, output } of testCases) {
  console.log(input, '=>', f(input) === output); // Equals?
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Comment: What would this look like when golfed?

Comment: @Someone well, the unit tests are excluded. Just declaration of `f` is what matters.

Comment: Ohh, I see—I didn't realize that last part was test cases. Sorry about that!
EDIT: -2 bytes: the `f=` doesn't need to be counted unless it's recursive (which it isn't).

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
≔Ｉ⪪Ｓ/θ≧÷⌈Φ⊕⌊θ∧ι¬⌈﹪θιθ¿﹪Ｘχφ§θ¹⪫θ/Ｉ∕§θ⁰§θ¹
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/NqsIwEIX3PkVwNYGIKchF6EoUQaEi@gShyW0H0qQ/U/XtY9JewcWdzcCcOd@cKWvVl17ZEHbDgJWDvRoI7q1FgpNrR7pTj64CLthyveSxdTxfFKqd129Y1WmRDvhAbQQr1AubsYEjWjJ9VMreNMaR0VCgm6QuUXZOAwp28QQfS@H1aD10giGfar6Fv@wjXf0zMjMpWCalTBQ6OW1eyZNFA7vGrARnjy6NpsA5M3Ywf8r03BwVvrz/oHgeQrb9WW@kDKuHfQM) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Ｉ⪪Ｓ/θ
```

Input the fraction.

```
≧÷⌈Φ⊕⌊θ∧ι¬⌈﹪θιθ
```

Reduce it to its lowest terms.

```
¿﹪Ｘχφ§θ¹
```

If the denominator is not a factor of `10¹⁰⁰⁰`...

```
⪫θ/
```

... output as a fraction, otherwise...

```
Ｉ∕§θ⁰§θ¹
```

output as a decimal.

81 bytes for the way overengineered version which works with arbitrary precision positive integer inputs:

```
≔Ｉ⪪Ｓ/θＷ﹪§θ±²§θ±¹⊞θι≧÷⌊θθ≔Ｘχ⌈Ｅ25⌕⮌Ｘ⁰↨§θ¹Ｉι⁰η¿﹪η§θ¹⪫…θ²/⁺÷§θ⁰§θ¹⭆Ｉ⁺η﹪×§θ⁰÷η§θ¹η⎇κι.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBfb4IwFMXf/RQNTyVhE1ppMD45lyUucTHqF2ikg5tVQFr88@nZLTJ1SgIN7em5v3O2uay3pdRtOzUGsoLOpLF0XWmwdF5UjV3bGoqM@gHxhp6Py96fDI45aEXookwbXdKpnRepOtF9QL5UJq2izAmftyMfH7JsTO42AY0WsrrMXUGWu4n2HQ6QqoAsoIBds6P7fmSPtyyPqqZRiAJ56gRoQT0WewH5gCKlK3VQtVG9EHVvEv/uWCI07EKCowlIeFlynAHf10z5P/6o48YiLP0sAUs6b7Wa5WXlDtlfN5OB0kb1uqVuzC3PPUDoP3oH5NKyi9KhdZcRoYfZwE6ZR4ub9zOri@O@G1UXsj7TH2wbIV89l3XStjET4ThhYiwSHgs@EiFPGGdDfBMeihEXMU/wlCXjULC4fTnoXw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔Ｉ⪪Ｓ/θ
```

Input the fraction.

```
Ｗ﹪§θ±²§θ±¹⊞θι≧÷⌊θθ
```

Reduce it to its lowest terms.

```
≔Ｘχ⌈Ｅ25⌕⮌Ｘ⁰↨§θ¹Ｉι⁰η
```

Find a power of `10` that the denominator might be a factor of.

```
¿﹪η§θ¹⪫…θ²/
```

But if it isn't then just output the fraction.

```
⁺÷§θ⁰§θ¹⭆Ｉ⁺η﹪×§θ⁰÷η§θ¹η⎇κι.
```

Convert the fraction to arbitrary precision decimal.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 137 bytes

```c
#define W(A,B)for(;d%A<1;q*=10,++c)n*=B,d/=A;
f(a,b){long n=a,d=b,q=1,c=0;W(2,5)W(5,2)printf("%ld%c%0*ld",d?a:n/q,47-!d,c*!d,--d?b:n%q);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDNjoIwFIXXw1N0mJC0WOwvLciQib6Ea6BiTJwqyqyMz@60KGAXbXPOl3NPbpPsm@bx@DK79mB3YAvXeIPa0wUWJlp/s6KLS0bxYtEgG5cbbEi5LoIWVrhGt@PJ7oEtK2zKGnclw01Jiy3kOEVbmGKOzpeD7VsYRkcTNRGNjybE5qdaWdJhqZNPg5vYXUlifuqVjTpU3Kcm/e7auzGgRqB9vgU4//VXGIaoCILf6mAhArfgYwCZElwADNyR1JGEEP/LllSnb4h@IkC@IWw5IQCwTA2IpFMKXUo1AlwwJQeAzYATl0q@CMEV9QSndCacLygfM7geMlyfTM6EyHJJJc9V9lbHGa/GYiKJGG2R5pm3OVdstFMmiVvFiGjNUz8rS3k@Il4jgzI2YoLnPkhoPTUaROKVcX/cScM4xuY2XiReCe6Pfw)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 30 bytes

Yet another xnor port. Like chunes' Factor port, it's shorter to return a `Rational` instead of an array if it can't be decimalized.

```ruby
->n,d{(n*1e16%d>0?1r:1.0)*n/d}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LZBbTsMwEEXFr9nEqFC16cP2jB3HQUpZSKmqoqRQqYQoSUGo7RJYAT8Vgm2wD1gNtlN_JDonM_dG_viqd_dvp8919r1r11P7M52Vk3w_LEdYoOnnM3mL9Q1yGY1KkR-7od_318fNtoCHom0YuPlJDRlcL3nT1puKN9V20w4FjOd3IlvAWET8aVXtD8WheFltoTgP3IpoNKjF4Mig2rUN9PpxDgL8M4OrfZut5y56cYShA94-L5ssq8P7GPWgD-ErK8q8-6nT38UlGkWJy_BHuxQtLfIkZgBoTfBaSucl1yZmpNDoYDFYx9xopshIr0nKoJ1UkhhREqZdh9VBK5tqqSk1NlQAqHO1CRWdw7NTfkUoBipOrXdEBp2LUQtFzicJxT7expQ671EEYITKKbeiksQ3BxYeGJKDkIYYGjwLD92l_AM)

Answer (score 2):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 29 bytes

```
16 17,.N>d Q",_ ="Q0.:"pop"?#
```

[Try it on scline!](https://scline.fly.dev/##H4sIALVO.mQCAzM0MjI0VjAyNDTW1.MyNFMwNNfR87NLUQhU0olXsFUKNNCzUirIL1CyVwYANfBn3yoAAAA)

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
16 17,.N>d Q ( ,_ = ) Q 0.: \pop ?#
```

Numbers in sclin are internally represented as rational numbers.

- `16 17,.N>d Q` represent the fraction as a decimal with 16 and 17 places
- `( ,_ = ) Q ... ?#` check if both representations are equal...

  - `0.:` if true, then get decimal representation
  - `\pop` otherwise, get rational representation